# apk file not generated

Tags: android, eclipse

I copied all the codes of an android project into a new android project manually. There is no error shown. But when I run it, apk is not generated but jar file is generated.
Console says `Could not find Asin.apk`. Could anybody please tell me what wrong am I doing ?

Comment: This is a long shot - but u sure u exported an android project in the wizard and havn't mistakenly chosen Java?

Comment: it is android project, i can see the android icon in package explorer

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

i think you must run your program, after that generate your apk. or simple way, run your program, after that go to your project address, in "bin" folder, there is your apk file. eclips generate it automatic.

Comment: after running, it is giving the error mentioned above. i checked bin folder as well but i found jar file with all classes not apk file

Comment: if your project didn't run so you can't get that apk file or generate it. fix your error. then you can get apk file.

Answer (score 0):

before running your imported app, do a thorough **Clean** and **Build** ..

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on Project.
2. Go to Properties.
3. Select 'Android'.
4. Uncheck 'Is Library' checkbox.

Then Run again, the `.apk`-file should be created in `bin` instead of `.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for contribution, please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your next post better.